# Using valuative criterion of separatedness. (Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne writes that for a scheme $X$ to be separated, it should not contain any subscheme which looks like a curve with a doubled point.

He then writes that another way of saying the above is:  If $C$ is a curve, and $P$ a point of $C$, then given any morphism of $C - P$ into $X$, it should admit at most one extension to a morphism of $C$ into $X$.

How do these conditions imply each other? I don't need anything rigorous, just an intuitive description.

Comment: Given a curve $C$ and a point $P$, we can always build a curve with a doubled point by gluing $C$ to $C$ along $C \setminus P$.